# Power Set of an Interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working through a set of problems, and I have found one that has me stumped. The question is asking for the power set of {x: x ∈ N, -10 < x < 10}. 
What has me confused is what I should include/exclude from the Power set. If x ∈ N, then would the power set simply contain all of the natural numbers less than 10? 
Any insight would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the power set of any given set $S$ is the collection of all subsets of $S.$ To figure out what *those* are, it's a good idea to start with what $S$ is. In this case, it is the set of all natural numbers less than $10,$ as you say. The power set, then, is the set of all sets $A$ such that each $x\in A$ is a natural number less than $10$. Letting $$S=\{x:x\in\Bbb N,-10<x<10\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\},$$ then the power set of $S$ is $$\bigl\{A:\forall x\in A,(x\in S)\bigr\}.$$

More explicitly, we could say that the desired set is $$\bigl\{A:\forall x\in A,(x\in\Bbb N\wedge x\le9)\bigr\},$$ or something similar. This would probably be the best case scenario, since the set has $512$ elements (or $1024,$ depending on your definition of $\Bbb N$), so list notation is certainly not a good option.